# Dealing has_one and singular resource with nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested, has-one

I have a User model, which has_one prestataire and has_one employeur. Previously on stackoverflow, someone advised me to declare singular resources, like:

```
resources :users do
resource: employeur
resource: prestataire
end
```

Instead of:

```
resources :users do
resources: employeurs
resources: prestataires
end
```

Thanks to rails, I didn't had to singularize all my controllers and views name files. Yet, when I create a user and am redirected to the employeur form, I get undefined method `user_employeurs_path', which is right since I only have a user_employeur_path. But I didn't ask for the plural in my user controller. Rails indicates that this NoMethodError happens in the first line of my employeur form  <%= form_for [@user, @employeur] do |f| %>, where one is redirected when a user is saved.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

#TODO index user doit être suprimé quand inutile pour dev
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        if params[:commit] == 'Prestataire'
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path(user_id: @user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations d'employeur" }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
        else 
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_employeur_path(user_id: @user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations de prestataire" }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        if params[:commit] == 'Prestataire'
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path(user_id: @user), notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        else 
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_employeur_path(user_id: @user), notice: "User was successfully updated." }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :surname, :forename, :civility, :phone)
  end

end
```

User form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :civility, 'Titre de civilité: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :civility %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :forename, 'Prénom: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :forename %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :surname, 'Nom de famille: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :surname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email, 'Email: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password, 'Mot de passe: ' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password, size: 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirmation de mot de passe: ' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, size: 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone, 'Numéro de téléphone: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Employeur" %>
    <%= f.submit "Prestataire" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Employeur form:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @employeur] do |f| %>
  <% if @employeur.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@employeur.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this employeur from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @employeur.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :siren, 'Siren: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :siren %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :societe, 'Société: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :societe %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :code_postal, 'Code Postal: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :code_postal %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

As for my new.html document for employeur:

```
<h1>New employeur</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use `url` parameter in this case. Try something like:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @employeur], url: user_employeur_path do |f| %>
   ...
```

Comment: Wow, impressive ! I wasn't expecting this one but it worked ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what's happening:

when you pass `<%= form_for [@user, @employeur] do |f| %>`, Rails will connect the objects (`@user` & `@employeur`) in the order you passed and the then append `path` to it. So this becomes `user_employeurs_path`. by convention it will pluralize your the last object (`employeur`) to infer your controller's name. that's how it gets: `user_employeurs_path`

so you would either have to pluralize your controller's resources to follow the convention. Or pass url to your path:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @employeur],  url: user_employeur_path do |f| %>
```